# S3 Bucket - File Browser Using Laravel and jQuery

Tags: php, laravel-5, amazon-s3, file-browser

I wants to prepare one front-end solutions for one of my s3 repository bucket. Where user can browse for all the directories and files inside it.

Basically the backend for subscription and apis is build in Laravel 5.4 Framework.

I go through so many packages but they are mainly used for local file browsing. One of suitable package i found while online searching and here it's [demo](http://fm.devale.pro/) and it's [github repository](https://github.com/servocoder/RichFilemanager). We can use s3 bucket for file browser and i have setup that in my machine as well.

**The main requirement is how to integrate in existing Laravel application?**

It's really very helpful if anyone can help to sort out this requirement, we can create github repo for this.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the way i have implemented my application.

1. I have integrated following libraries in my Laravel 5.4 application by modifying composer.json file

   `{
       "require": 
       {
           "servocoder/richfilemanager-php": "*",
           "aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.18.0"
       }
    }`

> **Note: servocoder/richfilemanager-php is not currently supported in laravel 5.2.* > version. Also if you install in this package in
>   Laravel 5.2 then you will get success for only installation but while
>   using connection with RFM you will get**
>
> *class log does not exists
>   error*

2. To overcome with above issue i have manually integrated richfilemanger-php library in application, by registering in auload application in composer.json file
   `"autoload": {
       "classmap": [
           "database",
           "app/filemanager"
       ],
       "psr-4": {
           "App\\": "app/"
       }
   },`

That's it, enjoy